# Подключение двух таблиц к одному .php

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема в том что у меня в БД `mysql` имеется 2 таблицы,и мне надо как-то одновременно из этих таблиц выводить значения.

На данный момент одна таблица подключена через

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `Name` = '%s' AND `pKey` = '%s'";
```

p.s. В будущем надо будет подключить и другие таблицы.

Comment: Разнообразными способами. Если данные в других таблицах как то связаны с данной, то скорее всего в том же запросе SQL описываете их взаимодействие и требуемый результат. А если не связаны - то делаете отдельные запросы и выводите данные из них в тех точках страницы, где это необходимо. Опишите подробнее, что вы имеете ввиду под "одновременным выводом значений"

Comment: Имел ввиду то что мне необходимо выводить значения в из двух таблиц
Для примера из первой таблицы я вывожу '$row['name']' ,а из второй $row['level']

Comment: А этот самый level как нибудь связан с этим name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если для обучения, то подойдет данный вариант:

```
SELECT `accounts`.name, `users`.level FROM `accounts`, `users`
```

Если таблицы связаны между собой или у вас их тысячи будут, то читайте про объединения таблиц (inner join cross join full join и т.д.), про внешние ключи, связи между таблицами. Это **мат часть** которая необходима при построении базы данных.